# Rails 3.1, rename ERB to HAML caused Template is missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I decided to start using HAML to speed up development, so, I decided to rename my view like this:

`new.html.erb` to `new.html.haml` but, it seems that rails no more connect it to the controller, here is the complete error message:

## Template is missing

Missing template quizzes/new, application/new with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in: * "C:/Users/Sam/RubymineProjects/hope/app/views" * "D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/kaminari-0.12.4/app/views" * "D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.4.8/app/views"

here is the new action:

```
def new
    @quiz = Quiz.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
    #  format.json { render json: @quiz }
    end
  end
```

so, what shall I do ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure to add `gem 'haml'` to your `Gemfile` and run `bundle install`; that way, Rails will know what to do with your HAML files.